# Store categories are not displayed

Tags: magento-1.7, category, magento-1

I recently upgraded Magento from 1.3 to 1.7 - everything appears to be working fine but there is a little issue.

I am unable to view my category on front page. I am displaying all my categories on a custom page and this function `Mage::helper('catalog/category')->getStoreCategories();` isn't working
- it returns `null`.

I know I can use the category collection methods to retrieve all my categories but my question is why this function returns `null`, despite the fact I have over 100 categories in my store.

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like either the store needs re-indexing, or the upgrade didn't quite go right.

1. Ensure FCP/FCC is disabled `(System > Configuration > Catalogue)`
2. Re-run all the indexes
3. Make sure the store root catalogue is set correctly `(System > Manage Stores)`

If this doesn't work/help, then repeat your upgrade again. `1.3` to `1.7` is a BIG jump (even 1.3 to 1.4.2 is a big jump). You are better staging the upgrade over two upgrades

```
1.3       ->   1.4.2.0
1.4.2.0   ->   1.7.0.2
```

Comment: root catalog is  set i have re-run all indexing everything is working fine except category

Comment: Start from the beginning and Run the upgrade again then.

Comment: But there is no other way?

Comment: You did a big upgrade and something fundamental isn't working. If you've followed the standard debug procedure and its still not working then you need to restart.

Comment: Ok let me check all over thing again